# Can't change cursor within a control

Tags: .net, winforms

I'm trying to do this within a control I've created:
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

During the initialization of the parent form, my control gets added to the
form, and while the control is being initialized, I call a method within the
control that sets the cursor to Cursors.WaitCursor, then processing
continues. I want the Cursor to remain that way until I set it back at any
given time, and if I don't set it back, I want to remain a WaitCursor.
I can't get this to work, I'm guessing it might have to do with the loading
of the form, resetting the cursor or something? How can I do this?

Comment: Need more info. I am assuming you're working with WinForms? It's possible that the cursor is being reset by `InitializeComponent()`. It's also possible (and more likely) that you just can't see the cursor changing because your UI thread is busy from the point when you set the cursor right up to the point when you reset it.

Comment: Post your code, I'm not clear on what you're trying to do from your post. Sounds like somewhere the form itself is overriding what your control is trying to do.